# Use attach point

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm newbie to dojo. I have created widget and executed it successfully. But now I want to use the concept of attach point here. Below is my code

### practice.html

```
<div>


</div>
```

### practice.js

```
define([ "dojo/_base/declare"
     , "dojo/text!./practice.html"
     , "dijit/_WidgetBase"
     , "dijit/_TemplatedMixin" 
     , "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"

    ], function(declare, _templateString, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin)
    {
    function trace(msg) {

        console.log("practice:", msg, arguments);
    }

    function Controller(w) {
        function myPractice(){
            alert("My Practice");
        }

    this.myPractice = myPractice;       
    }



    var d = 
    declare("Practice.practice", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],  {
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        templateString: _templateString
        , constructor: function(args) {
            declare.safeMixin(this, args);
        },
        postCreate: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            var controller = new Controller(this);
            //controller.myPractice();
            this.myPractice = controller.myPractice;
    }
    });
    return d;
});
```

And I'm executing this by using test.html

### test.html

```
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:/dojofiles/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="D:/dojofiles/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


    <script>

        showMyForm = function(){

            require(["Practice/practice"], 
            function(practice){

                var myObj = new practice();
                myObj.myPractice();
            });

        }
        showMyForm();       

    </script>


</head>
<body class="claro">

    <div id="myId" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">

</body>
</html
```

Where and how can I add `data-dojo-attach-point` and use it to execute my widget?

Answer (score 2):

If you start expanding your widget template (**practice.html**) with additional HTML nodes, and you would like to refer to some DOM node from within your JavaScript widget code (**practice.js**) then you use attach points, for example:

**practice.html**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" data-dojo-attach-point="textfield" />
</div>
```

**practice.js**

```
var d = declare("Practice.practice", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
  widgetsInTemplate: true,
  templateString: _templateString,
  constructor: function(args) {
    declare.safeMixin(this, args);
  },
  someFunction: function() {
    console.log(this.textfield.value); // Now you can use this.textfield thanks to the attach point
  },
  postCreate: function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    var controller = new Controller(this);
    //controller.myPractice();
    this.myPractice = controller.myPractice;
  }
});
```

However, I'm not quite sure if you're familiar with the concept of `data-dojo-attach-point`, because it doesn't execute your widget to be honest.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya attach points are only used within widgets. Your test HTML page is not part of a widget anymore so you don't use attach point in it. Attach points only make sense in widget context because you don't want to use IDs (because if you use the same widget 10 times, you can't use the same ID).

Comment: To render a widget on a HTML page, you use `data-dojo-type="Practice/practice"` on any attribute within the test HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Dojo attach points are used to refer html template’s dom nodes directly.

```
<div id="somenode"><span data-dojo-attach-point="anattachpoint"
     data-dojo-attach-event="click: clicked">Click me</span><br>
     <input data-dojo-attach-point="field"></div>
```

Javascript to declare a dijit using _AttachMixin.

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_AttachMixin", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(declare, dom, _WidgetBase, _AttachMixin) {

    var MyDijit = declare([ _WidgetBase, _AttachMixin ], {
        clicked: function(e) { this.field.value = "I was clicked"; }
    })

    var mydijit = new MyDijit({}, dom.byId('somenode'));
    mydijit.startup();
})
```

Here the dojo-attach-point is **"field"** and can be referred in your js file using "this.field."
In this example we are accessing attribute **value** of the dom which has dojo-attach-point **field** using **this.field.value**

You might think,we could just use ids in the html template, and then dom.byId() in the widget’s js. But if two or more widget instances are created, they’ll all have the same ids! The dom.byId call is no longer precise enough to return the node you want.
Further reference : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_AttachMixin.html